# Dashboard/Left Menu (tabs) Android pattern

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make application for tablet with Android 2.3 with this kind of design:

[Screenshot http://techpcnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/System-Mechanic-Free-10.6.2.7-550x411.jpg](http://techpcnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/System-Mechanic-Free-10.6.2.7-550x411.jpg)

Left menu on the left to navigate between functionalities. But this left menu also must have some indicators dependent on what user made in some right site pages (e.g. how many searches he had or how many info he have).

I don't know how to make this. I thought about Tabs with content made of Views. But then ActivityTab has a lot of code inside and i don't thing this is good idea overall (but at the same time it's good because one page have easy connetion with another page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use fragments to solve this. the left pane will be one fragment and the right pane another. Than you use the activity that the fragments reside in to send messages between the fragments. So the left pane will till the activity to till the right pane to load certain content.

Here is a great example:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/index.html